# Read certain column in excel given two other values match using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Month   Year    Open    High    Low Close/Price Volume
6   2019    86.78   87.11   86.06   86.55   1507828
6   2019    86.63   87.23   84.81   85.06   2481284
6   2019    85.38   85.81   84.75   85.33   2034693
6   2019    85.65   86.86   85.13   86.43   1394847
6   2019    86.66   87.74   86.66   87.55   3025379
7   2019    88.84   89.72   87.77   88.45   4017249
7   2019    89.21   90  87.95   88.87   2237183
7   2019    89.14   91.08   89.14   90.67   1647124
7   2019    90.39   90.95   89.07   90.59   3227673
```

I want to get the monthly average of: Open  High    Low Close/Price

How do i set two values (Month, Year) as parameters for getting a value that is in another column?

```
df = pd.read_excel('DatosUnited.xlsx')
month = df.groupby('Month')
year = df.groupby('Year')
june2019 = month.get_group("6")
year2019 = year.get_group('2019')
```

I tried something like this, but i dont know how to use both as a filter simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` with multiple columns, and then you can use `.mean()` to get the desired averages:

```py
df.groupby(["Month", "Year"]).mean()
```

This outputs:

```py
              Open     High      Low  Close/Price      Volume
Month Year
6     2019  86.220  86.9500  85.4820       86.184  2088806.20
7     2019  89.395  90.4375  88.4825       89.645  2782307.25
```